# How to get the result of MySQL explain query into a file?

Tags: mysql, explain

I am unable to get the results of the explain query in its normal tabular format or json format into a file.

```sql
select * from table_name into outfile 'file.format';
select trace from information_schema.optimizer_trace into outfile 'file.json' lines terminated by '';
```

The above queries work, and I get the file. But the following queries do not create the file.

```sql
explain select * from table_name into outfile 'file.txt';
explain format=json select * from table_name into out 'file.json' lines terminated by '';
```

Is there any way to achieve this? It is preferable if the tabular explain results are written in text file with column names and table borders.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [syntax of EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html), no.

You can run the explain from the command line however:

```
mysql -e 'EXPLAIN ... ' > /tmp/myexplain.json
```

SQL isn't responsible for the pretty presentation of data, [Workbench](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-tutorial-visual-explain-dbt3.html) is one option.